HDD LED stays on while on battery after kernel upgrade in Ubuntu 24.04, but turns off when plugged in
I'm experiencing an unusual issue with my laptop after upgrading to a newer kernel version in Ubuntu 24.04. The HDD LED stays on constantly when the laptop is running on battery power, even when there are no apparent I/O operations. However, the issue disappears as soon as I plug in the charger.
I suspect this might be related to changes in the ACPI handling in the new kernel, but I'm not sure how to address it.
My question is: How can I resolve the HDD LED issue when on battery power after the kernel upgrade? Is there a way to tweak ACPI settings or simulate a plugged-in state to prevent this from happening?
inxi -Fxxxrz
 
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
    clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: Xfce v: 4.18.1 tk: Gtk v: 3.24.41 wm: xfwm4 v: 4.18.0
    with: xfce4-panel tools: xfce4-screensaver vt: 7 dm: LightDM v: 1.30.0
    Distro: Xubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) base: Ubuntu
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP ProBook 650 G3 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 82AA v: KBC Version 49.52 serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: X4N12AV uuid: <superuser required> UEFI: HP v: P83 Ver. 01.38
    date: 12/28/2020
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 30.5 Wh (93.0%) condition: 32.8/48.0 Wh (68.3%)
    volts: 12.9 min: 11.4 model: Hewlett-Packard Primary type: Li-ion
    serial: <filter> status: charging cycles: 252
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i5-7300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check rev: 9 cache: L1: 128 KiB
    L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 500 high: 501 min/max: 400/3500 cores: 1: 500 2: 500
    3: 500 4: 501 bogomips: 21599
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1,
    HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:5916 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Lite-On HP HD Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-9:3 chip-ID: 04ca:7053 class-ID: 0e02
    serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 compositor: xfwm4 v: 4.18.0 driver:
    X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.21x7.99")
    s-diag: 414mm (16.31")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: ChiMei InnoLux 0x15be res: 1366x768 hz: 60
    dpi: 101 size: 344x193mm (13.54x7.6") diag: 394mm (15.5") modes: 1366x768
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: iris x11: drv: iris
    inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
    device-ID: 8086:5916
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-31-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: e1000e
    v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:15d7 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24fd class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 700.51 GiB used: 35.98 GiB (5.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD Green 2.5 240GB
    size: 223.57 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 1100
    scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: TwinMOS model: SSD size: 476.94 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 980 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 451.74 GiB used: 35.88 GiB (7.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb4
  ID-2: /boot size: 943.2 MiB used: 94.4 MiB (10.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb1
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sdb2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 14.9 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/sdb3
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C pch: 33.5 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2040 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2029 pm: snap pkgs: 11
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
    1: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted universe multiverse
    2: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security restricted multiverse universe main
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.41 GiB used: 2.01 GiB (13.0%)
  Processes: 236 Power: uptime: 4m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: deep
    wakeups: 0 hibernate: platform Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5)
    default: graphical
  Compilers: clang: 18.1.3 gcc: 13.2.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21
    running-in: xfce4-terminal inxi: 3.3.34


Thanks in advance, I had no problem using 22.04, I might revert back to that version for now.
